# Jquery selecting next div after $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a drop down menu button that when clicked displays the previously hidden div under it.

This code works without `$(this).next` but it will display all div's with class `.menudrop` because there are multiple buttons and drop downs on the page; I am trying to only change the display on the next `.menudrop` after the `.dropclick` that was pressed.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/nuen3735/1/

```
<div class='playbox'>
    <div class='playbox2 playboxplayer player'>
        <div class='play' key='respect.mp3' name='Respect' tag='tagtest'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='playbox2 playboxbpm bpm'>85 BPM</div>
    <div class="playbox2 playboxname name">Respect</div>
    <div class='playbox2 playboxkeywords keywords'>Slow, Smooth, RnB</div>
    <div class='playbox2 playboxlength length'>02:12</div>
    <div class='playbox2 playboxbuy buy'>
        <div class='mp3buy droptrack' data-product-id='Respect' data-product-key='3c31060e1038c3fe3e9cb0f069d6f33b'>+</div>
    </div>
    <div class='menudrop'>(dropdown)</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".droptrack").on('click', function() { 
    $(this).next(".menudrop").slideToggle('display', function(i, v) {
        return v == 'none' ? 'inline-block' : 'none' 
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nuen3735/. Can you please provide more detail about the problem you're having.

Comment: There is no sig like that for jQuery `slideToggle()` method but anyway this would work...  And `.dropclick`, what is that?

Comment: Just use $(this).next('div') and that's it.

Comment: It seems to work fine when it is simple, but the actual site has alot of extra divs I left out to try to keep the question simple, I edited code and added JS Fiddle of actual site code, I think it has somthing to do with the way the divs are structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).next()` moves to the next sibling. In your code, `.menudrop` is not a sibling of `.droptrack`, but of its father. What you should do is:

```
$(this).parent().next('.menudrop')
```

(Tip: proper HTML formatting would help you next time)

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I just had to change find to next $(this).parent().next('.menudrop') https://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/nuen3735/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().next('.menudrop')
```